# Rails3:how to register scss template handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, sass

I'm interested how can I register a .scss template handler in Rails 3.1 . I know that I already can use .scss files in the app/assets directory, however I need to have access to the application environment and instance variables.

I'm trying to do something like this (the end goal is to have dynamic scss files):

```
file: app/views/css/layout.css.scss.erb

$site_width = <%= @site.width %>px;

.container { width: $site_width; }
```

The "problem" with the assets directory is that we don't have access to the application environment there.

I tried to achieve it this way, however it isn't the correct way :)

```
file: initializers/scss_template_handler.rb

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :scss, Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate.new
```

Thanks for any help or ideas in advance!

Comment: Can you give some more info about why you need to pass in a value to the CSS? What are you trying to achieve? There are some alternative (cleaner) approaches to doing this that avoid having to mess with the handlers (and I can't answer the question directly!).

Comment: "the end goal is to have dynamic scss files" . E.g. we can have user-specific stylings of layouts and colors for a site and those stylings could be stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.

By following this gist: https://gist.github.com/827572 you can easily register a :scss template handler!

However here comes another showstopper :) - processing a file by multiple template handlers. I'll open a new questions for that.